# How do I set up Plone 4 to authenticate using LDAP?

Tags: ldap, plone

Plone 3 had PloneLDAP, which is [not compatible with Plone-4](http://plone.org/products/ploneldap#1291275871). So how do I set up Plone 4 with an LDAP server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try looking at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.ldap/

**Do not**, by *any* means, install the LDAPUserFolder, even if you see it listed as installable. Honestly, I don't know why it's still shown there, as installing it will break your Plone site severely.

Comment: plone.app.ldap has been the "right way" to do LDAP in Plone for a while, certainly for the last couple of Plone 3.x releases.

Comment: Well, yes, but even plone.app.ldap still says "you need to install PloneLDAP", and the link in the question claims the problem is actually in building "plone.app.ldap".  It doesn't seem to have been turned into a bug report, and it seems suspect - but then I don't use LDAP.  I would suggest the OP should try telling us exactly how PloneLDAP is broken on Plone4.

Comment: I add plone.app.ldap to buildout.cfg (sections eggs and zcml) and run buildout. After build and restart plone activate **only** LDAP support in Plone control_panel. It works! thanks